# Cannot import certificate into the Keyvault

Tags: powershell, import, certificate, azure-keyvault

I have the following powershell code that i need to use to import a certificate into the keyvault:

```
###############################################################################

<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Import-KeyVaultCertificate

.DESCRIPTION

    Import-KeyVaultCertificate

.PARAMETER VaultName

.PARAMETER Name

.PARAMETER Password

.PARAMETER Version

.PARAMETER DisableVersions

.NOTES
    This template allows to write secrets into the KeyVault if they are not present. If they are present, the script will ignore it.

.EXAMPLE
    Import-KeyVaultCertificate.ps1 -VaultName 'vaultname' -Name 'certificatename' -Password 'certificatepassword' -Thumbprint 'certificatethumbprint' -FilePath 'certificate.pfx'

.EXAMPLE
    Import-KeyVaultCertificate.ps1 -VaultName 'vaultname' -Name 'certificatename' -SecurePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'certificatepassword' -AsPlainText -Force) -Thumbprint 'certificatethumbprint' -FilePath 'certificate.pfx'

#>

# ' char inc as Notepad++ language recognition does not like get-help contents
##############################################################################

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetname = "String")]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $VaultName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $Thumbprint,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $FilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "String")]
    [string] $Password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "SecureString")]
    [securestring] $SecurePassword,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string] $Version,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch] $DisableVersions
)
begin {
    $Verbose = ($PSBoundParameters['Verbose'] -eq $true) -or ($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')
    $KeyVaultParams = @{}
    if ($Version -ne $null) {
        $KeyVaultParams.Add('Version', $Version)
    }
}
process {
    try {
        $KeyVault = @(Get-AzureRmResource -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq $VaultName) -and ($_.ResourceType -eq 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults')})
        if ($KeyVault.count -ne 1) {
            Write-Error -Message ('KeyVault "{0}" not found - Internal Error.' -F $VaultName) -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message ('KeyVault "{0}" not found - Internal Error.' -F $VaultName) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    $GetKeyVaultCertificate = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $Name @KeyVaultParams
    if (($GetKeyVaultCertificate -ne $null) -and ($GetKeyVaultCertificate.Name -eq $Name) -and ($GetKeyVaultCertificate.Thumbprint -eq $Thumbprint)) {
        Write-Warning -Message ('Certificate "{0}" with Thumbprint "{1}" is present in KeyVault "{2}"' -F $GetKeyVaultCertificate.Name, $GetKeyVaultCertificate.Thumbprint, $KeyVault.Name)
    }
    elseif (($GetKeyVaultCertificate -eq $null) -or (($GetKeyVaultCertificate -eq $null) -and ($GetKeyVaultCertificate.Thumbprint -ne $Thumbprint))) {
        try {
            $CatchMessage = 'Failed to upload the certificate "{0}" in key vault "{1}".'
            if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'String') {
                $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
            }
            Write-Output ($NewCertValue = Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $Name -Password $SecurePassword -FilePath $FilePath -Verbose:$Verbose -ErrorAction Stop)
            if ($DisableVersions) {
                $CatchMessage = 'Unable to retrieve certificate "{0}" in key vault "{1}".'
                (Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $Name -IncludeVersions | Where-Object {$_.Enabled })  | ForEach-Object {
                    if ($_.Version -ne $NewCertValue.Version) {
                        $CatchMessage = 'Failed to disable version for certificate "{0}" in key vault "{1}" [Version: ' + $_.Version + '].'
                        Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAttribute -VaultName $VaultName -Name $Name -Version $_.Version -Enable $false -Verbose:$Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error -Message ($CatchMessage -F $Name, $VaultName) -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    }
}
```

If i try to use it, it asks me for a version, although i specified the parameter is not mandatory. If i remove the `@KeyVaultParams`, i get to the point where the script in the catch message:

```
'Failed to upload the certificate "{0}" in key vault "{1}".'
```

Did a debug on the `Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate` and i it states that the certificate is not found, which is correct, but it does not go to the line to import it. 
If i use the  `Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $Name -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force:$true 'xxxxxx') -FilePath 'cert.pfx'`cmdlet and import the certificate, next time i use the script i get the warning - which is what i want. Means the certificate is in the keyvault and the Thumbprint matches.

So 2 issues:
1. Version seems to be manadatory - how do i get around that?
2. The certificate is not imported if it doesn;t exist in the keyvault - Why?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
In the meanwhile i found the issues:

1. `@KeyVaultParams` - i removed the `-eq $null` from `$Version -ne $null`
2. the logic here was faulty: `(($GetKeyVaultCertificate -eq $null) -or (($GetKeyVaultCertificate -eq $null)`. It should be `(($GetKeyVaultCertificate -eq $null) -or (($GetKeyVaultCertificate -ne $null)`
3. I was parsing the password as as securestring when the script was asking for a plaintext password.
4. Added a `Write-error $_.Exception.Message` before the last `catch` to see the error, which was: `The specified network password is not correct.`

I hope this helps people that want to import a certificate in a more.. fancy way :)